# Reading a dictionary of dictionary in Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, django

I am using Django to return a dictionary of dictionary via JSON to JQuery which is something like :

```
'{u'Potatoes': {'Key1': u'500', 'Key2': u'500', 'Key3': u'500'}, u'Wheat': {'Key1': u'500', 'Key2': u'500', 'Key3': u'500'}, u'Pears': {}}`.
```

In Jquery I convert the JSON back to an object and I get something like:

`Object {Potatoes: Object, Wheat: Object, Pears: Object}`.

I tried using the each statement to iterate but its not helping. I am trying to access the key and values in each dictionary i.e Potatoes, Wheat and Pears.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({type: "GET",
                url: "/get_uncategorized/",

                success:function(result){

                //if localstorage not equal to result object then update with localstorage

                $(result).each(function(index,value){

                    $(value).each(function(i,j){console.log(i,j)});

                });



              }

    });
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you tried?

Comment: Not appear valid `JSON` ? Does _"convert the JSON back to an object"_ return `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` ?

Comment: `I tried using each` is not a proper problem statement without seeing your code. Also check browser console for errors. You also haven't specified what you are trying to do with the data

Comment: to loop over object don't use `$.fn.each` use `$.each( result, function(key, value){})`. Also specify `dataType` to be sure `result` isn't string

Comment: @charlietfl that fixed it! Thanks everyone for the help.